# animated output uing php with dynamic data comming from database

Tags: javascript, php, css, database, animation

I need to archive something like this. (please check image) [image]

**Explanation** :

- This is an Single page but having set of data. `Slide 01` will hold few min the `Slide 02` ... like wise it will go on..
- this depends on data which coming from Database.
- one slide hold 8 row. If data length is 20 then (20/8) = 3 sides are there.

How to archive this? Need to know is there any Library or any code helps you own. help me on this

**FYI**: you may ask **`where is your code ?`** or **`What you tried so far`** there is just 18 rows(basic html). If need will add. but don't thinks it will help the core of the issue.

Comment: Google: ajax based page slider

Comment: Do a google for `javascript slide show` and pick one of the 20 million results

Comment: Thanks sir. but I get all them for image sliders only